# Usar función en `methods` que retorna boolean para imprimir condicionalmente en el template

Tags: vue.js

Estoy tratando de hacer algo muy simple, pero obviamente me estoy perdiendo algo.

Lo que quiero es renderizar condicionalmente algunas etiquetas en el `template`.

Para eso creé una función en la propiedad de `methods` y en el `template` intenté de varias maneras imprimir algo basado en lo que devuelve esa función.

Pero siempre imprime 'is snew', aunque hardcodee `return false` en la función (no pongo la condición que hará que la función devuelva verdadero o falso aquí, porque ni siquiera puedo hacer que funcione hardcodeando el return).

Eso es en un componente, pero un ejemplo mínimo sería el siguiente:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    isNew() {
      console.log('isNew function called')
      return false;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  
  <div>{{ isNew? 'is new': 'is not new' }}</div>
  
  <div v-html="isNew? 'is new': 'is not new'"></div>
  
  <div v-if="isNew">is new</div>
  <div v-else>is not new</div>
  
</div>
```

Tampoco imprime en la consola lo que puse en `console.log('isNew function called')`.

¿Cómo puedo imprimir condicionalmente en la plantilla algo basado en el `return true / false` de una función?

---

Edit: Snippet basado en el primer comentario de BetaM

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    isNew() {
      console.log('isNew function called')
      return false
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  
  <div>{{ (isNew)? 'is new': 'is not new' }}</div>
  
  <div v-html="(isNew)? 'is new': 'is not new'"></div>
  
  <div v-if="(isNew)">is new</div>
  <div v-else>is not new</div>
  
</div>
```

No Funciona.

Comment: Prueba asi `{{ (isNew) ? 'new' : 'no new' }}`

Comment: Lo único que te esta faltando es envolver entre paréntesis el nombre de la función

Comment: O si no vas a envolver entre paréntesis a la función entonces necesitas indicarlo de esta forma  y también debe funcionar: `{{ isNew() ? 'new' : 'no new' }}`

Comment: @BetaM `{{ isNew() ? 'new' : 'no new' }}` funcionó perfecto, por alguna razón la de envolverlo entre paréntesis no lo hace. Si lo publicas como respuesta, con gusto la marco como aceptada.

Comment: No gracias, estoy totalmente Ok con la idea de que tu mismo publiques la solución al problema ;) adelante

Comment: Por cierto yo quitaría de la pregunta las propuestas que funcionaron ya que al menos a mi parecer parece ser que incluiste la solución en la pregunta y mejor la dejaría en el espacio que le corresponde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bien, gracias a la guía en los comentarios bajo la pregunta, me ha funcionado de esta manera (llamando a la función como se lo haría a una función de javascript `isNew()` en vez de pniendo sólo el nombre `isNew`):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    isNew() {
      console.log('isNew function called')
      return false
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  
  <div>{{ isNew()? 'is new': 'is not new' }}</div>
  
  <div v-html="isNew()? 'is new': 'is not new'"></div>
  
  <div v-if="isNew()">is new</div>
  <div v-else>is not new</div>
  
</div>
```

Busqué un poco y la explicación parece ser la que encontré en las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635404/parentheses-while-calling-a-method-in-vue) de SO:

Básicamente, el controlador de eventos puede ser:

- un nombre de método, como `@input="changeName"`.
- una declaración de Javascript válida, como `@input="changeName()"`.

Es cierto que ambos casos son válidos en Vue. Pero hay algunas diferencias.

```
@input="changeName"
```

El objeto de evento se pasa al controlador de eventos como primer argumento cuando se vincula solo el nombre del método como controlador de eventos.

```
@input="changeName()"
```

Alternativamente, se puede utilizar una llamada de método "real" como controlador de eventos. Esto le permite pasar cualquier argumento personalizado al método.

---

Vue realiza comprobaciones automáticamente para detectar en qué caso se trata.

Si está interesado, consulte estos códigos básicos en https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/19552a82a636910f4595937141557305ab5d434e/dist/vue.js#L10086:

```
 var handlerCode = isMethodPath
      ? ("return " + (handler.value) + "($event)")
      : isFunctionExpression
        ? ("return (" + (handler.value) + ")($event)")
        : handler.value;
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo que necesitas es computed

```
 computed: {
    isNew: function () {
      console.log("is new")
      return false
    }
```

Comment: Convendría agregues un poco de contexto a tu aporte, checa [answer]